# Environment for Counting Names and Marking the count as Subscript

Tags: environments, subscripts

For typesetting a religious document explained as below

1. This contains verses of list of names separated by commas.
2. A counter is to be initiated and will be incremented with each name.
3. Each name has to be underlined and this counter has to be printed as
   subscript

I tried to define a command but I request help in defining an environment which takes a comma separated list of names and that contains some line breaks also, which have to be properly typeset as line breaks only.

I am not an expert of LaTeX but I tried typesetting some Theses which never needed this feature. Thanks in advance.

I tried the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,ulem}
%%%%%%%Definition of Name Command
\newcommand{\scdots}[2][]{\mathinner{#1\overset{#2}{\cdots}#1}}
\newcommand\ovline{\bgroup\markoverwith{{\rule[-0.5ex]{5pt}{0.4pt}}}\ULon}
\newcounter{nameCounter}
%\setcounter{\nameCounter}{0}
\newcommand {\name}[1]{{\ovline {#1}}
\stepcounter{nameCounter}$_{\arabic{nameCounter}}$}
\begin{document}
\name{First One}   \name{Second Name}  \name{Third Name}
%%%%%Request for defining an Environment of Names  - as mentioned below
%\begin{names}
%First One, Second One, Third One \\
%Fourth One, Fifth Name.
%\end{names}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation with `xparse` and `environ`.

The environment's contents is split into lines at `\\`. Then each line is split at commas and each item is fed as argument to `\name`. The lines are rebuilt with comma-space between items, and printed in sequence.

Final punctuation must be added as an optional argument to the environment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath,ulem,xparse,environ}

%%%%%%%Definition of Name Command
\newcommand{\scdots}[2][]{%
  \mathinner{#1\overset{#2}{\cdots}#1}%
}
\newcommand\ovline{%
  \bgroup\markoverwith{\rule[-0.5ex]{5pt}{0.4pt}}\ULon
}
\newcounter{nameCounter}
%\setcounter{\nameCounter}{0}
\newcommand{\name}[1]{%
  \ovline{#1}%
  \stepcounter{nameCounter}$\,_{\arabic{nameCounter}}$%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{names}[1][]
 {
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_majety_name_lines_seq { \\ } \BODY
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_majety_name_lines_seq \l_majety_name_firstline_tl
  \majety_name_process_line:Vn \l_majety_name_firstline_tl { }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_majety_name_lines_seq
   {
    \majety_name_process_line:nn { ##1 } { ,\\ }
   }
  #1
 }

\seq_new:N \l_majety_name_lines_seq
\seq_new:N \l_majety_name_oneline_seq
\tl_new:N \l_majety_name_firstline_tl
\tl_new:N \l_majety_name_firstname_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \majety_name_process_line:nn #1 #2
 {
  #2 % can be empty or ',\\'
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_majety_name_oneline_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_majety_name_oneline_seq \l_majety_name_firstname_tl
  \majety_name_process_name:Vn \l_majety_name_firstname_tl { }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_majety_name_oneline_seq
   {
    \majety_name_process_name:nn { ##1 } { ,~ }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \majety_name_process_name:nn #1 #2
 {
  #2 % can be empty or ',~'
  \name{#1}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \majety_name_process_line:nn { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \majety_name_process_name:nn { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\name{First One}   \name{Second Name}  \name{Third Name}

\bigskip

\begin{names}[.]
First One, Second One, Third One \\
Fourth One, Fifth Name
\end{names}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I could not avoid saying thanks to @egreg for quick and perfect reply.

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety You're very welcome! `:)`

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMajety Of course you may also say thank you by accepting the answer and (as soon as you have enough reputation) up-voting it.